# How To get Positional Occurrence of strings in List using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var a = new List<string>() {"aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","cc","aa","aa","cc","cc" };
```

I want to find occurrence count of all strings, for above list i want output like:

```
Index    String   Count
0        aa       2
2        bb       3
5        cc       1
6        aa       2
8        cc       2
```

but as i tried groupby it gives the total count not positional.
how i can get this?

> edit: i expect more than 10 million entries in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following.

**Solution Using Linq**

```
var a = new List<string>() {"aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","cc","aa","aa","cc","cc" };
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count())
                    .Where(x => x == 0 || a[x - 1] != a[x])
                    .Select((x,index) => new Stat<string>
                            {
                                Index =index, 
                                StringValue = a[x], 
                                Count = a.Skip(x).TakeWhile(c => c == a[x]).Count() 
                            });
```

Where Stat is defined as

```
public class Stat<T>
{
  public int Index{get;set;}
  public T StringValue {get;set;}
  public int Count {get;set;}
}
```

**Update** 
**Using Iterator**

```
public IEnumerable<Stat<T>> CountOccurance<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var lastItem = source.First();
    var count = 1;
    var index= 0;
    foreach(var item in source.Skip(1))
    {
        if(item.Equals(lastItem))
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new Stat<T>
            {
                Index = index,
                StringValue = lastItem,
                Count = count
            };
            count=1;
            lastItem = item;
            index++;
        }

    }

    yield return new Stat<T>
    {
        Index = index,
        StringValue = lastItem,
        Count = count
    }; 
}
```

You can then fetch the result as

```
var result = CountOccurance(a);
```

Comment: ok, but i need to take care of performance also, i think there can be a better solution, as i need to run this on 100 million rows of data

Comment: oh ok. Would be ideal if you could mention number of rows you would expect in OP.

Comment: i will have to run several tests, before marking this as an answer, thank you

Comment: @AlokSaini, this code answered your question before you added a new request, turning it into a _chamaloen_ answer. If this answer solved your _original_ question, then you should accept it and post a new question for the n° of rows/performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use this logic multiple times you can consider writing your own extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SpecialGroup<TKey>> GroupAccordingToSuccessiveItems<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;

        TKey latestKey = default(TKey);

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            TKey key = keySelector(item);


            if (index != 0 && !object.Equals(key, latestKey))
            {
                yield return new SpecialGroup<TKey>
                {
                    Index = index - count,
                    Obj = latestKey,
                    Count = count
                };

                count = 0;
            }

            latestKey = key;
            count++;
            index++;
        }

        yield return new SpecialGroup<TKey>
        {
            Index = index - count,
            Obj = latestKey,
            Count = count
        };
    }
}

public class SpecialGroup<T>
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public T Obj { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call it,

```
var result =
            a.
            GroupAccordingToSuccessiveItems(i => i);
```

This will iterate all the list once.